# Apache server-status returning 404, then redirecting to my Wordpress install

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess

I'm trying to get Munin's various Apachie plugins to work on my web server, but I'm hitting issues. Upon asking Munin to check available plugins, two of the three Apache plugins return an error saying that

> apache server-status cannot be found

I've got `mod_status` turned on etc, and as far as I know, everything's set up correctly.

I've tried opening `localhost/server-status` using `Lynx`, at which point I get a 404 error and my Wordpress error page is shown (the one you get when you try to access a page that doesn't exist.)

Now presumably this is something to do with how I have Apache serving a Wordpress install etc. The web site lives in `/var/www/wordpress`, with the `index.php` file one level up and the .htaccess file amended as per the Wordpress instructions. It works fine, but I've a niggling feeling that when Munin/Lynx tries to load localhost/server-status, it's looking for it in `/var/www/`.

So, how do I tell Apache where to actually look when requesting server-status?

---

Here's my httpd.conf file.

```
ServerName localhost



<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName oliverhaslam.com
ServerAlias oliverhaslam.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ojhaslam.co.uk
ServerAlias ojhaslam.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/sites/photo365/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.ojhaslam.co.uk
ServerAlias www.ojhaslam.co.uk
RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) http://ojhaslam.co.uk/$1
DocumentRoot /var/sites/photo365/
</VirtualHost>

<Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from  all
</Location>
```

If I remove the last part, I get a 'forbidden' error instead of the error outlined above.

---

Appears the issue is my `.htaccess` file. Removing that means the server-status works, but obviously Wordpress links don't. Here's the file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Next two don't fix the issue.    
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
#RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What are the relevant sections of Apache's configs for your WordPress site, and enabling mod_status?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wordpress's .htaccess file sends all non-existing files and directories to be processed by Wordpress. Try excluding the server status urls too.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't actually fix the issue, as you can see in my edit above, but it will work for some. I had to use the other excluded line from above but leave this one hashed out to make it work. My problem was having them both de-commented together.

Answer (score 1):

Since I got helped with this post and in case you also failed to apply becomingwisest's answer, like I did initially, you should exactly put the condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
```

before rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That's why Oliver Haslam still have the same trouble, because he put the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
```

above other condition.

Hope this can help another people came here :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but if you want to use `/server-status/?refresh=2` for auto-update each N seconds change the provided line to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status/?$ [NC]
```